# Finding the fft of a inputted wav. file

Tags: python

Im doing a project on a raspberry pi 3, the goal is to apply a band-pass filter to the signal but i am currently having trouble getting the fft of the given signal. I am using python3, here is my code thus far:

```
import scipy
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
from scipy.signal import hann
from scipy.fftpack import rfft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from threading import *

input_data = read("/home/pi/Music/doorbell-1.wav")
np.array(input_data[1],dtype=float)
audio = input_data[1]
#apply a Hanning window
window = hann(1024)
audio = audio[0:1024] * window
# fft
mags = abs(rfft(audio))
# convert to dB
mags = 20 * scipy.log10(mags)
# normalise to 0 dB max
mags -= max(mags)
# plot
plt.plot(mags)
# label the axes
plt.ylabel("Magnitude (dB)")
plt.xlabel("Frequency Bin")
# set the title
plt.title("doorbell Spectrum")
plt.show()

#ERROR
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/scimath.py:310: RuntimeWarning: 
divide by zero encountered in log10
return nx.log10(x)
MaynoothTest.py:18: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
mags = 20 * scipy.log10(mags)
MaynoothTest.py:20: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
mags -= max(mags)
[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py:531: ComplexWarning: 
Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
```

Comment: What's your problem with this code?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/MaynoothTest.py", line 14, in <module>
    audio = audio[0:1024] * window
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1024,2) (1024,)                  This is the error message.

Comment: You have Left and Right channel in audio (shape (1024,2)). Try selectring one of them.

Answer (score 0):

`audio` contains both channels (Left and Right). You need to select one with: `audio = audio[0:1024, 1]`.

Comment: I tried this and a new error occurred;                   
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/scimath.py:310: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10
  return nx.log10(x)
MaynoothTest.py:20: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  mags -= max(mags)

Comment: First, I think you should use [`fft(mags)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fft.html#scipy.fftpack.fft). Second, can you tell me the values you have in mags after the fft? you can check if you have nan or inf with `np.isnan(mags)` or `np.isinf(mags)`

Comment: What should the fft(mags) replace?

Comment: `mags = abs(fft(audio))`

Comment: I've now replaced that line but i am still getting a few runtime errors. the value of mags after the fft is preformed is all true.

Comment: Copy and paste the error message into your question.